# Handle deferred deep link with a custom URL that does not directly provides an APK

Tags: android, branch.io

I am implementing a deferred deep link for my Android app using Branch.io

I am working on the use case where the user clicks the link but does not have the app installed (my link already works when the app is installed). 
For now my app is not hosted on the Play Store, but in Fabric instead. Thus I have setup my deep link to redirect the user to a url like : https://betas.to/... so that he can eventually download Beta, then download the app.

Unfortunately, I can't make the following use case to work :

-> User clicks the deep link from Android device (without app)

-> User reaches Fabric web page to provide his email for testing

-> User opens Fabric email

-> User downloads  Beta (optional)

-> User downloads app withing Beta

-> App starts, and takes the deferred deep link into account

Problem occurs in the last step: the initial deep link is not taken into account anymore. I guess this is because the app is not opened from the link in the end.

Can I expect this flow to work somehow ? If not, I would like to know if the URL I provide in Branch dashboard must **directly** point to an APK file.

**UPDATE 1**

I just realized that I am getting an error related to branch when I test my deferred deep link (following [Branch deferred deeplink testing procedure](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#test-deep-link)). This error only happens when I install the app from Android Studio just after I clicked the link.
I feel like something is preventing Branch to catch the app installation event properly.

Here is what I get :

> Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/android/installreferrer/api/InstallReferrerStateListener;
>       at void io.branch.referral.InstallListener.captureInstallReferrer(android.content.Context,
>   long, io.branch.referral.InstallListener$IInstallReferrerEvents)
>   (InstallListener.java:54)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch.registerAppInit(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener,
>   io.branch.referral.ServerRequest$PROCESS_WAIT_LOCK) (Branch.java:2318)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch.initializeSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener)
>   (Branch.java:2272)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch.initUserSessionInternal(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener,
>   android.app.Activity, boolean) (Branch.java:1255)
>       at boolean io.branch.referral.Branch.initSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener,
>   android.app.Activity) (Branch.java:917)
>       at boolean io.branch.referral.Branch.initSessionWithData(android.net.Uri,
>   android.app.Activity) (Branch.java:1037)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch.startSession(android.app.Activity)
>   (Branch.java:2522)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch.access$1000(io.branch.referral.Branch,
>   android.app.Activity) (Branch.java:73)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchActivityLifeCycleObserver.onActivityStarted(android.app.Activity)
>   (Branch.java:2458)
>       at void android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(android.app.Activity)
>   (Application.java:231)
>       at void android.app.Activity.onStart() (Activity.java:1271)
>       at void android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart() (FragmentActivity.java:564)
>       at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart() (AppCompatActivity.java:177)
>       at void com...MyActivity.onStart()
>   (MyActivity.java:48)
>       at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(android.app.Activity)
>   (Instrumentation.java:1256)
>       at void android.app.Activity.performStart() (Activity.java:6972)
>       at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2937)
>       at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3045)
>       at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread,
>   android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
>       at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message)
>   (ActivityThread.java:1642)
>       at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
>       at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
>       at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6776)
>       at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])
>   (Method.java:-2)
>       at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
>       at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[])
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1386) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class
>   "com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerStateListener" on
>   path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.myapp.debug-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.debug-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.myapp.debug-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>       at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String)
>   (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>       at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean)
>   (ClassLoader.java:380)
>       at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String)
>   (ClassLoader.java:312)
>       at void io.branch.referral.InstallListener.captureInstallReferrer(android.content.Context,
>   long, io.branch.referral.InstallListener$IInstallReferrerEvents)
>   (InstallListener.java:54)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch.registerAppInit(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener,
>   io.branch.referral.ServerRequest$PROCESS_WAIT_LOCK) (Branch.java:2318)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch.initializeSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener)
>   (Branch.java:2272)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch.initUserSessionInternal(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener,
>   android.app.Activity, boolean) (Branch.java:1255)
>       at boolean io.branch.referral.Branch.initSession(io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchReferralInitListener,
>   android.app.Activity) (Branch.java:917)
>       at boolean io.branch.referral.Branch.initSessionWithData(android.net.Uri,
>   android.app.Activity) (Branch.java:1037)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch.startSession(android.app.Activity)
>   (Branch.java:2522)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch.access$1000(io.branch.referral.Branch,
>   android.app.Activity) (Branch.java:73)
>       at void io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchActivityLifeCycleObserver.onActivityStarted(android.app.Activity)
>   (Branch.java:2458)
>       at void android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(android.app.Activity)
>   (Application.java:231)
>       at void android.app.Activity.onStart() (Activity.java:1271)
>       at void android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart() (FragmentActivity.java:564)
>       at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart() (AppCompatActivity.java:177)
>       at void com.....MyActivity.onStart()
>   (MyActivity.java:48)
>       at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(android.app.Activity)
>   (Instrumentation.java:1256)
>       at void android.app.Activity.performStart() (Activity.java:6972)
>       at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2937)
>       at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3045)
>       at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread,
>   android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
>       at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message)
>   (ActivityThread.java:1642)
>       at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
>       at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
>       at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6776)
>       at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])
>   (Method.java:-2)
>       at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1496)
>       at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[])
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1386)

The following line is :

> BranchSDK: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/installreferrer/api/InstallReferrerClient;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The missing class (`com.android.installreferrer.InstallReferrerClient`) is a dependency of Branch, but isn't included automatically. You have to add it to your build yourself.

```
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
```

See it in [Branch's gradle file](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/blob/efb033820a75fe3d42f767925963f2f8a34efe94/Branch-SDK/build.gradle#L16).

It was added in [version 2.17](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/commit/2de9bd84c878e1791a55e439d6b6440c21769923#diff-ac3200858728914b2948a96c53c600ba), but documentation doesn't seem to have caught up.

It is possible that this stack trace is a bit of red herring.. after reading the commit. The library catches the ClassNotFound exception and remembers that the class isn't available. It just also helpfully prints the exception.

However, the [install referrer package](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library) is involved in tracking referrers across installs, so does match your steps to reproduce.

Comment: This worked for me. Should be the accepted answer !

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;** You should always call this method at the start of your activity :

```
Branch.getInstance().initSession(BranchReferralInitListener callback, @NonNull Uri data, Activity activity)
```

**EVEN IF YOU HAVE A NULL Uri**

---

Since Branch API annotated this parameter with @NonNull, I got confused.

I checked the source code and I confirm that a null value is properly handled by Branch. When null is passed-in, Branch will automatically detect if it is a cold start, or a deferred deep link.

This is the relevant [piece of code from their github](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/Branch-SDK/src/io/branch/referral/Branch.java) :

```
// In case of a cold start by clicking app icon or bringing app to foreground Branch link click is always false.
if (intent.getData() == null || (!isActivityCreatedAndLaunched && isIntentParamsAlreadyConsumed(activity))) {
    // Considering the case of a deferred install. In this case the app behaves like a cold start but still Branch can do probabilistic match.
    // So skipping instant deep link feature until first Branch open happens
    if (!prefHelper_.getInstallParams().equals(PrefHelper.NO_STRING_VALUE)) {
        JSONObject nonLinkClickJson = new JSONObject();
        try {
            nonLinkClickJson.put(Defines.Jsonkey.Clicked_Branch_Link.getKey(), false);
            nonLinkClickJson.put(Defines.Jsonkey.IsFirstSession.getKey(), false);
            prefHelper_.setSessionParams(nonLinkClickJson.toString());
                isInstantDeepLinkPossible = true;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What is wrong in the code of the official documentation given for the onStart method ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Regis_AG The code from Branch sample is correct, but I find it confusing because it can break the signature of their own `initSession()` method (null can be passed-in when calling `getIntent().getData()` while the paramter is annoted with @NonNull. I updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Brian from Branch here.

If regular deep linking works when the app is installed, deferred deep linking should work as well. Please make sure that you are initializing Branch in the onStart method and overriding onNewIntent:

- https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#initialize-branch

Also, I would test deferred deep linking by clicking a Branch link and building the app on the device via Android Studio:

- https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#test-deep-link

The custom URL does not need to **directly** point to an APK file. If you are still running into issues, could you please write in to integrations@branch.io.

Comment: Branch initialization seems good to me. I followed the steps to simulate the link behavior upon app installation and I get an error related to branch I guess. I updated my question :)

Comment: Any solution to this problem ? I don't understand how to implement the accepted answer. Thanks.